# What impurity index (Gini, entropy?) is used in TensorFlow Random Forests with CART trees?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, cart-analysis

I was looking for this information in the `tensorflow_decision_forests` docs (https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests) (https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests/api_docs/python/tfdf/keras/wrappers/CartModel) and `yggdrasil_decision_forests` docs (https://github.com/google/yggdrasil-decision-forests).

I've also taken a look at the code of these two libraries, but I didn't find that information.
I'm also curious if I can specify an impurity index to use.

I'm looking for some analogy to sklearn decision tree, where you can specify the impurity index with `criterion` parameter.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html

For TensorFlow Random Forest i found only a parameter `uplift_split_score`:

> uplift_split_score: For uplift models only. Splitter score i.e. score
> optimized by the splitters. The scores are introduced in "Decision trees
> for uplift modeling with single and multiple treatments", Rzepakowski et
> al. Notation: `p` probability / average value of the positive outcome,
> `q` probability / average value in the control group.
> - `KULLBACK_LEIBLER` or `KL`: - p log (p/q)
> - `EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE` or `ED`: (p-q)^2
> - `CHI_SQUARED` or `CS`: (p-q)^2/q
> Default: "KULLBACK_LEIBLER".

I'm not sure if it's a good lead.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't use `uplift_split_score`, because it is `For uplift models only`.
Uplift modeling is used to estimate treatment effect or other tasks in `causal inference`